Trying to add elements in a array without any duplicates(as per a given range n). As soon as a dup no comes up, i can add only upto n-1 range
"""
Trying to add elements in a array without any duplicates(as per a given range n). 
As soon as a dup no comes up, i can add only upto n-1 range while avoiding the dup element entered. 

"""

arr = []
a = int(input('Enter a range: '))

for i in range(a):
    i = int(input())
    if i in arr:
        print('its a dupl,enter another')
        continue
    else:
        arr.append(i)
        
        
    
    
print(arr)

##############

Enter a range: 6
1
2
3
8
9
1 ---> 'the dup ele'
its a dupl,enter another
[1, 2, 3, 8, 9]----> can only enter 5(ie n-1 range)

As you notice above, the array only takes 5 elements out of the given range 6.
How can i ensure to have complete 6 non-dup elements in the array.
i tried
not in instead of in
break instead of continue
used further:
i = int(input()) inside if
but in vain.

Please put effort into formatting your question before you post it. See this handy guide. As an aside, in Python, we call these lists not arrays.

Anyway, I'll give you a hint, the problem is how you are iterating. What are other methods you have learned for iterating so far? for and while... how do you choose between the two?

Your for loop runs a times regardless of whether the value to be added to your list is a duplicate. Also, arr is a list - not an array

you can use a while loop, with range and use if else to check like this example -
range = 6 # take range input from user
arr = []

while len(arr) < range:
    i = int(input()) # the numbers you want to check
    if i not in arr:
        arr.append(i)
    else:
        #parse a message that's its a duplicate or something

hope it works.

range is not a good variable name to use, it shadows the built-in range

(If the name of a variable changes color when you paste it into Stack Overflow, that's usually a good sign that it's a built-in.)

Once you know what the "range" value is you can write a loop based on the length of the list compared to this "range".
When acquiring integer values using input() it's best practice to check that what's been entered is actually a valid integer.
Do not confuse a Python list with an array.
I suggest:
def getint(prompt):
    while True:
        x = input(prompt)
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"{x} is not a valid integer")

alist = []

nvals = getint("Enter a range: ")

while len(alist) < nvals:
    v = getint("Enter a value: ")
    if v in alist:
        print(f"{v} is a duplicate")
    else:
        alist.append(v)

print(alist)

